# Swap two arrays without completely allocating a third (C++)

Tags: c++, c

I have two arrays of type `Region`, both of size 1000, and at every iteration of a loop I want to swap the two of them (by swapping their memory addresses). I was hoping this would work:

```
        Region *swap = (Region*)myRegions;
        myRegionsLast = myRegions;
        myRegions = (Region[1000])swap;
```

Line one seems fine. The second and third lines are invalid assignments, as you apparently can't re-assign that type.  The third line is also invalid because you can't cast to the type `(Region [1000])`.  Obviously I don't want to allocate whole new Region[1000] if I can help it.  Can someone help me accomplish what I want?

Comment: No idea, but no need to allocate a third array at all -- you can just use a single temporary Region variable since you are doing it index by index.

Comment: Why aren't both pointers instead of having a pointer and an array?

Comment: @Jeremy, or use `std::swap()`.

Comment: @myrkos myRegions and myRegionsLast are arrays of type Region and size 1000. swap is just a pointer to a region, just to swap the two.

Comment: If the array is fixed size and you're in C++ land,  `std::array<Region, 1000>::swap` might be a good alternative (similar to Wyzard's comment).

Comment: @myrkos I guess I see what you mean, just make them both dynamically allocated instead of both fixed size.

Comment: @Wyzard:  You can make your comment an answer.  (I'd upvote it.)

Comment: This sort of thing is not only covered by standard textbooks and tutorials, but it's also an SO duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3393518/777186

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because you cannot assign a whole array at once. You can assign a pointer, however:

```
Region reg1[1000], reg2[1000];
Region *myRegionsLast = reg1;
Region *myRegions = reg2;
```

Now your swap routine is going to work without further modifications.

You could also swap arrays one element at a time, but it is going to involve a lot more data copying.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating just a variable of the content of Region type and iterating through it...

```
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
    tempRegionTypeVariable = myRegionsLast[i];
    myRegionsLast[i] = myRegions[i];
    myRegions[i] = tempRegionTypeVariable;
}
```

Hope this helps..
Here "tempRegionTypeVariable" is just a temporary variable or an Object. Not an Array..

Comment: I'd prefer to just switch the addresses instead of swapping every variable, though, as speed is very crucial for this application!

Comment: It's a good thought, but there is a much faster way, as Wyzard and Dasblinkenlight have noted.

Comment: Yup.. If speed is a critical component then my method is not the best. It's the simplest and easiest though..  :)

Answer (score 0):

A couple other valid answers were posted in the comments:

1. Use std::swap() / std::array::swap
2. Make them dynamically allocated arrays instead of static